# Login with JMeter for performance testing

Tags: authentication, automation, jmeter

I've used BlazeMeter Recording tool and run it on Jmeter but in response data "CSRF token validation failed." I have to test web application and same issue occurring there in response data it displaying same log in page without error.

Comment: Share your test plan and error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a different structure of your test to make it behave like a real browser:

- Open Login Page ([HTTP Get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) Request)

  - Extract `_csrf_token` value from the response and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- Perform Login ([HTTP Post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request). At this stage you need to provide credentials and **_csrf_token** from the previous request.

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Site](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more information with regards to bypassing [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) in JMeter tests.